# How to write a loop to run chi square of a two columns data frame?

Tags: r, loops, chi-squared

I have this data.frame:

```
pb2 <- read.table(header=T, text="
    PT1     PT2
1   0        13
2   4636    4623
3   2        11
4   4634    4625
5   3        11
6   4633    4625
7   2        17
8   4634    4619
9   6        25
10  4630    4611")
```

I want to run several chi-squared tests and extract the p-values as follows, but obviously in a more efficient way, with a loop for example:

```
 tests <- list()
 tests[[1]] <- chisq.test(pb2[c(1,2),], correct=F,simulate.p.value =T,B = 10000)
 tests[[2]] <- chisq.test(pb2[c(3,4),], correct=F,simulate.p.value =T,B = 10000)
 tests[[3]] <- chisq.test(pb2[c(5,6),], correct=F,simulate.p.value =T,B = 10000)
 tests[[4]] <- chisq.test(pb2[c(7,8),], correct=F,simulate.p.value =T,B = 10000)
 tests[[5]] <- chisq.test(pb2[c(9,10),], correct=F,simulate.p.value =T,B = 10000)
pb3 <- sapply(tests, function(x) {
   c(p.value = x$p.value)
 })

 pb4<-as.data.frame(pb3)
```

I really appreciate if you can show me how to make a loop for this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your data frame for every two rows and then use `lapply` to loop through the list of data frames and do `chi-square.test`:

```
lapply(split(pb2, (1:nrow(pb2) - 1)%/%2), 
    function(data) chisq.test(data, correct = F, simulate.p.value = T, B = 10000)$p.value)

# $`0`
# [1] 0.00029997

# $`1`
# [1] 0.01989801

# $`2`
# [1] 0.05649435

# $`3`
# [1] 0.00089991

# $`4`
# [1] 0.00149985
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It was what I needed!